# Center multiple DIV:s

Tags: html, css, center, centering, text-align

Having trouble centering some logos. I tried to used `margin: auto` as well as  `text-align: center` but can't seem to get it working.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XNA4/3/)

Comment: In the code that you have linked, what element are you trying to centering the divs in? Currently, the `button-circle` class is floating to the left.

Comment: What do you mean centering? As I saw to your fiddle each log is next to another logo. Do you want each one of them to be centered and not any other logo be next to them?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @RobinAbony: I want to center the collection of `button-circle` elements in the `footer-container` so that the middle of the elements is in the center and the other two are offset to the side.
@ChristosPaisios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would you like something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7XNA4/4/)?

I add this class

```
#footer-container {    
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and made some changes in this class ( ex: remove the float )

```
.button-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 66px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will looks like this .I think that it is your desire result!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#footer-container{
    text-align:center;
}
.button-circle:last-of-type{ /*remove right margin from last div*/
    margin-right:0;
}
.button-circle {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

NOTE:

`inline-block` adds `white-space` between elements. Write elements on same line to remove `white-space`.

Write:

```
<div class="button-circle">.........</div><div class="button-circle">...
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="button-circle">
.......
</div>
<div class="button-circle">
.......
</div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XNA4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have given both  the code html and css  check it 

<div id="footer-container">
    <div id="followicon">
        <div class="button-circle">
          <div class="bild"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1faoLxr.jpg" style="width: 66px"></div>
          <div class="block">facebook</div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-circle">
          <div class="bild"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hVdiFAx.jpg" style="width: 66px"></div>
          <div class="block">twitter</div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-circle">
          <div class="bild"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/WJGtp0A.jpg" style="width: 66px"></div>
          <div class="block">vimeo</div>
        </div>
            </div><!--end of the followicon -->
      </div>
            <div>





//css code

#footer-container {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#followicon {
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0px auto;
}







.block{
  position:relative;
  width: 66px;
  height: 25px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:100;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.button-circle {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 66px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left:13px;
}

.bild {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```